# JQTouch AJAX Link / Content wont load into jqtouch

Tags: jquery, mobile, jqtouch

On my index.html file, I have a link to a script:

```
    <div id="myList">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>myList</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="rounded">
<li class="arrow"><a href="/scripts/lookup.php?id=3294&oid=492">Affiliation</a></li>
</ul>
```

I replaced lookup.php with the default source of ajax.html from jqtouch:

```
<div id="get"> 
    <div class="toolbar"> 
        <h1>GET Example</h1> 
        <a class="back" href="#">AJAX</a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="info"> 
        This page was loaded via AJAX.
    </div> 
    <ul class="rounded"> 
        <li><a href="#livetest">Test live events</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div> 
<div id="livetest"> 
    <div class="toolbar"> 
        <h1>Events test</h1> 
        <a class="back" href="#">AJAX</a> 
        <a class="button goback" href="#home">Home</a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="info"> 
        This is a test of live events.
    </div> 
</div>
```

And when I click the link, it displays without any of the jqtouch interface. It just displays in plain html. I'm also using expressionengine so I have a feeling that might be the culprit but can someone provide a work-around for this problem?

On another note, I also notice that when I click the link the address bar shows m.blah.com/scripts/lookup.php instead of m.blah.com/#get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out...

slideSelector: "div#myList a"

it works now.